# Accessing Connection String and SqlParameters: Is there a leaner or less repeatitive code approach?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following Connection String, the two methods below handle different stored procedures: I feel like this code is a little verbose and wondering if there is a possibility to cut down on possible redundancies?

Is there a more leaner way to call individual methods using the same connection string.

In a nutshell; I am simply asking if there is a way to do what I am doing with less code?

I have all of this in a class called `Database`:

```
class Database
{
  public static Int32 intReturnCode { get; set; }
  public static string DatabaseStatus { get; set; }

  static string source = 
  @"Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True; Timeout=30";

  public static void InsertTracking(string UserID, string Department)
  {
    try
    {
      using (SqlConnection databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(source))
      {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertUser", databaseConnection))

        {
          cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

          cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.NChar, 8));
          cmdSQL.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = UserID;
          cmdSQL.Parameters["@UserID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

          cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Department", SqlDbType.NChar, 4));
          cmdSQL.Parameters["@Department"].Value = Department;
          cmdSQL.Parameters["@Department"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

          cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReturnCode", SqlDbType.Int));
          cmdSQL.Parameters["@ReturnCode"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;                  

          databaseConnection.Open();
          cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
          intReturnCode = Convert.ToInt16(cmdSQL.Parameters["@ReturnCode"].Value);

          databaseConnection.Close();
        }
      }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       DatabaseStatus = ex.Message;
     }
   }

  public static int InitializeDatabase()
  {
    try
    {
      using (SqlConnection databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(source))
      {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("usp_InitializeDatabase", databaseConnection))

        {
          cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReturnCode", SqlDbType.Int));
          cmdSQL.Parameters["@ReturnCode"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; 

          databaseConnection.Open();
          cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
          intReturnCode = Convert.ToInt16(cmdSQL.Parameters["@ReturnCode"].Value);

         databaseConnection.Close();
       }
     }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     DatabaseStatus = ex.Message;
   }

   return intReturnCode;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can refactor these into a less verbose format. Identify everything that's the same and move them into their own method, what may be tricky is the parameters you provide to the stored procedure. You have options there too - this link might help http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html

Comment: We built a class and method that takes a shorthand form and builds the actual command and connection string internally.  It handles the input vs output, return value, etc.  So basically we call a class method with the sql command text (stored procedure name or ad hoc sql), and pass it a list of parameters as key-value pairs. (input/output parameters require a somewhat different format.)  Another option would be to use an ORM like NHibernate. If you want to keep explicit control over everything, go with something like the firs option.

Answer (score 0):

you can share the SqlCommand (of usp_InsertUser SP) and SqlConnection instants. Needless to create them by 'Using' again and again.

```
 static class Database
 {
     public static Int32 intReturnCode { get; set; }
     public static string DatabaseStatus { get; set; }
     static SqlConnection databaseConnection;
     static SqlCommand sqlCmd_usp_InsertUser;
     static SqlCommand sqlCmd_usp_InitializeDatabase;
     string source = @"Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True; Timeout=30";

     //static initalizer
     static Database()
     {
         string source = @"Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True; Timeout=30";
         databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(source);

         // usp_InsertUser
         sqlCmd_usp_InsertUser = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertUser", databaseConnection);
         sqlCmd_usp_InsertUser.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         sqlCmd_usp_InsertUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.NChar, 8) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
         sqlCmd_usp_InsertUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Department", SqlDbType.NChar, 4) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
         sqlCmd_usp_InsertUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReturnCode", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue });
     }


     public static void InsertTracking(string UserID, string Department)
     {
         try
         {
             if (databaseConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                 databaseConnection.Open();
             sqlCmd_usp_InsertUser.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = UserID;
             sqlCmd_usp_InsertUser.Parameters["@Department"].Value = Department;
             sqlCmd_usp_InsertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
             intReturnCode = Convert.ToInt16(sqlCmd_usp_InsertUser.Parameters["@ReturnCode"].Value);
             databaseConnection.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             DatabaseStatus = ex.Message;
         }
     }

     public static int InitializeDatabase()
     {
         try
         {
             SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("usp_InitializeDatabase", databaseConnection);
             cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReturnCode", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue });

             if (databaseConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                 databaseConnection.Open();

             cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
             intReturnCode = Convert.ToInt16(cmdSQL.Parameters["@ReturnCode"].Value);

             databaseConnection.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             DatabaseStatus = ex.Message;
         }
         return intReturnCode;
     }
 }
```